# SharePoint Online - JSON - highlight selected page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, json-formatting, json, sharepoint-library

I have followed the guidance from [this site](https://exceltrainer.be/sharepoint/603/) and successfully created a menu based on Pages Library. However, I would like to modify the JSON so that the selected page (i.e. the page that is currently opened) is highlighted in the menu. How do I do that?

JSON used:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "href": "= @currentWeb + '/SitePages/' + [$FileLeafRef]",
      "title": "[$Title]"
    },
    "style": {
      "text-decoration": "none"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "_comment_": "Main Div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-borderColor-white"
        },
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "align-items": "stretch",
          "flex-direction": "row",
          "padding": "0",
          "margin-bottom": "2px",
          "min-width": "99%",
          "max-width": "930px",
          "border-width": "1px",
          "border-style": "solid",
          "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "_comment_": "Title div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "=if( [$PageOrder] == 0 , 'ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-neutralLighter ms-borderColor-neutralLight--hover ms-borderColor-contrastWhiteSelected', 'ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt') + ' ms-bgColor-purpleLight--hover ms-borderColor-themePrimary  ms-borderColor-neutralLight--hover ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary ms-fontColor-neutralLight--hover'"
            },
            "style": {
              "flex-grow": "1",
              "display": "flex",
              "flex-direction": "row",
              "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
              "align-items": "left",
              "width": "230px",
              "padding-top": "5px",
              "padding-bottom": "5px",
              "padding-left": "7px",
              "margin-left": "=if( @rowIndex == 0 ,'0','28px')",
              "border-width": "1px",
              "border-style": "solid",
              "border-radius": "0.2em"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "style": {
                  "padding": "7px",
                  "font-size": "14px",
                  "padding-left": "=if([$PageOrder] == 0 , '0', '14px')"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "=if(@rowIndex == 0 , 'HomeSolid',if([$PageOrder] == 0 , 'BulletedTreeList', ''))"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "txtContent": "=[$Title]",
                "style": {
                  "display": "=if([$Title] == '', 'none', 'block')",
                  "font-size": "16px"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `@isSelected` toke in SharePoint JSON formatting to identify the selected item, check: [SharePoint: Highlight selected list item rows using JSON formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/23/sharepoint-highlight-selected-list-item-row-using-json-formatting/). Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Also, can you add the current JSON you are using to your question?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, I honestly don't know where to add @isSelected.
I cannot paste the JSON here as it is much too long. You can however have a look at the site I referred to in my post, the JSON is there.

Comment: Are you using the exact same JSON from the linked site? Also, you can "edit" your original question to paste the JSON if you are not using the exact JSON from the site.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I have just added the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ganesh mentioned, you need to use @isSelected here is a snippet.

```
{
  ...
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "_comment_": "Title div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(@isSelected, 'selectedStyle', if([$PageOrder] == 0 , 'ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-neutralLighter ms-borderColor-neutralLight--hover ms-borderColor-contrastWhiteSelected', 'ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt') + ' ms-bgColor-purpleLight--hover ms-borderColor-themePrimary  ms-borderColor-neutralLight--hover ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary ms-fontColor-neutralLight--hover')"
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```